# adt quits unexpectdely while creating new android project

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adt

I am using ADT on mac osx 10.6.8, everything was fine, I was able to create new project and able to import, had fun (I am new to android development, actually any development for that matter). But from one day whenever I create a new android project the ADT quits unexpectedly.

I thought there may be some fault with software or configuration, so I downloaded the latest version from Google website(v 22.3.0), then I updated all the android SDK tools( just in case).

But even after that my ADT quits unexpectedly.Then I checked, its not just when I create a new project, even when I import a project the ADT quits unexpectedly.

So I tried for solution in web, but none of the solutions worked: 
1.unchecking the build automatically option, 
2.trying to create a new android project with lower SDK version. etc .

so I tried to do something on my own, than I found, while creating a new project, in second step of the wizard **"if I uncheck the option create custom launcher icon"** than a new project gets created but it won't contain any source files(both java and xml layout file) and in that project if I create a new activity, the wizard will completes but no files will be generated.

Please help me, I am new to android programming and I have some work( small project as part college) to complete.

**Here is the new thing, I did some more work on that,
Whenever I create a new workspace with options checked, then I will be able to create new projects and all i.e everything will work fine(normal), but once I close ADT and reopen, everything will go back to that abnormal state.**

Comment: Seeing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on "Project" and uncheck "Build Automatically", 
then prior to running a project, do "Build" and "Clean".